# Can PMF of transformed discrete RV sum to less than $1?$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand an exercise about transformation of random variables. Because the result is giving a value lower than 1 (at least in my head), and I'm not sure that's possible, given that random variables should always total to 1. Here's the example:

Let $X$ be a discrete R-valued random variable with p.m.f. $f_X,$ where $\mathrm{supp}(f_X) = \{-2,-1,0,1,2\},$ and $f_X(-2) = 3/20,$ $f_X(-1) = 7/20,$ $f_X(0) = 5/20,$ $f_X(1) = 4/20,$ $f_X(2) = 1/20.$

Let $g: R \rightarrow R$ be defined by:
$g(x) := |x|,$ for $ -3/2 <= x <= 3/2,$ and $x - 1,$ otherwise. Let $Y = g(X)$

The exercise asks to give all values of $f_Y(y)$

So my thought process here is that when you apply $g(x),$ you get:

$g_X(-2) = -2 -1 = -3,$ which is not in $f_X,$ therefore equal to $0.$

$g_X(-1) = 1 = f_Y(1) = 4/20 + 7/20 + 1/20$ (since we have to sum all values that will result in 1, which is  $12/20.$

Likewise, $g_X(1) = 1 = f_Y(1) = 12/20.$

Also, $g_X(2) = 2 - 1 = f_Y(1) = 12/20.$

Then, $g_X(0) = 5/20.$

The problem is that $12/20 + 5/20 = 17/20,$ therefore it could not be a random variable.

What am I missing here? Or which step am I doing wrong?

This is my first post to math stackexchange, so suggestions on how to better format my questions are appreciated! I hope it's clear enough to understand tho.

Comment: The new random variable $Y$ takes the values $g(-2), g(-1), g(0), g(1), g(2)$, which are (listed in the same order) $-3, 1, 0, 1, 1$. That is to say, $Y$ takes on just 3 values: $-3, 0, 1$. Can you find $f_Y(-3)$, $f_Y(0)$, and $f_Y(1)$? The trickiest one is $f_Y(1) = P[Y=1] = P[g(X)=1]$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting.

Comment: @JohnDawkins the exercise doesn't give a value for (−3), that's why I assumed it's 0. What makes you think that this value may exist? Anyway if it does it should take the place of (−3), which is 3/20. As for your question [()=1] should be equal to 12/20 if we are talking about c.d.f., but for each individual element it should be g_X(2) = 1/20, g_X(1) = 4/20 and, g_X(-1) = 7/20 following your logic I believe.

Comment: $f_Y(-3) = P[Y=-3] = P[X=-2] = 3/20=0.15$.

Comment: $g_X(-2) = -3$ is not in the support of $X,$ but it is in the support of $Y,$ which is what matters.

Comment: "the exercise doesn't give a value for $f_Y(−3)$, that's why I assumed it's $0$." The reason the exercise doesn't give a value for $f_Y(−3)$ is because it is up to **you** to find the value of $f_Y(−3)$ from the information that was given.

Comment: There **is no function** in this question named $g_X$. There is only the function named $g$, and it is not a pmf. Also, when you write such nonsensical expressions as "$g_X(1) = 1 = f_Y(1) = 12/20$" you are literally saying that $1 = 12/20,$ which of course is false. Notation matters. Use it carefully and correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For verifying your work:  A simulation in R of 100,000 realizations of each random variable gives good approximate
probabilities and provides the opportunity for a
graphic display of the distributions of $X$ and $Y$.

```
set.seed(120)
x = sample(-2:2, 10^5, rep=T, p=c(3,7,5,4,1)/20)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -2.000  -1.000  -1.000  -0.352   0.000   2.000 
table(x)/10^5
x
     -2      -1       0       1       2 
0.14947 0.35154 0.25046 0.19857 0.04996
```

The table shows approximate probabilities
$p_X(x) = (3/20,7/20,5/20,4/20,1/20)$ for $x=(-2,-1,0,1,2),$
respectively.

```
table(x)/10^5

     -2      -1       0       1       2 
0.14947 0.35154 0.25046 0.19857 0.04996
```

Transformation:

```
y = abs(x)
y[x==-2] = -3
y[x==2] = 1
    
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-3.0000  0.0000  1.0000  0.1517  1.0000  1.0000 

table(y)/10^5
y
     -3       0       1 
0.14947 0.25046 0.60007 # aprx 3/20, 5/20, 12/20
```

The table shows approximate values of probabilities $(3/20, 5/20, 12/20).$

In the histograms below, histogram bars show simulated
proportions of values of $X$ (beige) and $Y$ (blue). Colored dots show
exact probabilities, and illustrate that $X$-values
$-1, 1,$ and $2$ are transformed to $Y$-value $1.$

[image]

R code for figure:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, br=-2.5:2.5, ylim=c(0,.6), col="wheat")
  farb.x = c("red", "blue", "green3", "blue", "blue")
  points(-2:2, c(3,7,5,4,1)/20, pch=19, col=farb.x)
 hist(y, prob=T, br=-3.5:1.5, col="skyblue2")
  farb.y = c("red", "black", "black", "green3", "blue")
  points(-3:1, c(3,0,0,5,12)/20, pch=19, col=farb.y)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

*Note:* This exercise can be used to illustrate
that while $E(Y)$ can be found by definition as

$$E(Y) = \sum_{\mathrm{all\,}y}  yp_Y(y)
= (-3)\frac{3}{20} + (0)\frac{5}{12}+(1)\frac{12}{20} = \frac{3}{20}.$$

$E(Y)$ can also be found by the 'law of the unconscious statistician' as follows:

$$E(Y) = E(g(X)) = 
\sum_{\mathrm{all\;}x}g(x)p_X(x)\\
= g(-2)\frac{3}{20}+g(-1)\frac{7}{20}+g(0)\frac{5}{20}+g(1)\frac{4}{20}+g(2)\frac{1}{20}\\
= \frac{-9}{20} + \frac{7}{20}+\frac{4}{20}+\frac{1}{20} = \frac{3}{20}.$$

Thus, it is not necessary to know the distribution of $Y$ in order to find $E(Y),$ if $Y = g(X)$ and the distribution of $X$ is known.